# How do I implement random selection in my code?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I would like to display the value of `G[Ht]`, which is actually the sum of the equation `Ht = (rt - c) d - f [d]`, but I am having some trouble, so I ask for your help.

To determine this value, I use the values ​​present in a table which I call `dlist` and which depends on a probability `p` which is random. I think my problem arises because I can't add an expression in my code which indicates that the probabilities are random.

Below is my code:

```
c = 0.058;
rc = -0.06;
th = 0.80;

g1[ε_] = 2*(ε + 0.5)*(ε + 0.5);
        
dmin = 1;
dmax = 3;
pas = 0.01;
dlist = Table[d, {d, dmin, dmax, pas}]
Length[dlist]

rt = Simplify[((1 + rc) (1 - p th ))/(1 - p) - 1]

Ht = (rt - c) d - f[d]
```

This is code to calculate `G[Ht]`

```
Htlist = Table[Ht[dlist[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[dlist]}];

GHtlist = Table[g1[Htlist[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[dlist]}];
choose_d = 5;
results = GHtlist[[choose_d]];

Print["Valeur de d fixée = ", dlist[[choose_d]]]

For[i = 1, i < Length[dlist] + 1, i++, 
  {Print[i "ème d fixé = ", dlist[[i]]],  
   Print["i = ", dlist[[i]]], 
   Print["G(Ht) = ", results[[i]]]}]
```

Comment: I suspect that part of the answer lies in your use of `=` where `:=` would be more appropriate.  If you don't understand the difference, have a look at the documentation.  They are also known as `Set` and `SetDelayed`.

Comment: Have you seen `RandomReal`? That allows you to generate real (pseudo-)random numbers, uniformly distributed in a given interval. See `RandomVariate` for more general probability distributions.

Comment: Henrik,can you please tell me where exactly can i add the 'RandomReal' in my equation?This is exaxtly my big problem.

Comment: @EmilioDas what physical / numerical problem are you actually trying to solve? This code is mostly strange fragments and it's hard to understand what the intent is. What is `choose_d` for? Note that you shouldn't use underscores in variable names.

Comment: @flinty the 'choose_d' in my last code, was a method to pick up a d in my dlist. But i think the idea wsn't  good.

Answer (score 1):

I have made `Ht` and `rt` functions accepting a `d` value and a `p` value. The `p` takes on random values from a list `pvalues` when `Ht` is called in the `MapThread`. Does this produce the output you were expecting?

```
c = 0.058;
rc = -0.06;
th = 0.80;
dmin = 1;
dmax = 3;
pas = 0.01;
dlist = Range[dmin, dmax, pas];
g1[ε_] := 2*(ε + 0.5)*(ε + 0.5);

f[d_] = Min[{-0.02 + 0.0231397 d, 0.1}];

rt[d_, p_] := ((1 + rc) (1 - p th))/(1 - p) - 1
Ht[d_, p_] := (rt[d, p] - c) d - f[d]
pvalues = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[dlist]];
Htlist = MapThread[Ht[#1, #2] &, {dlist, pvalues}];
GHtlist = Map[g1[#] &, Htlist];
formatted = MapThread[{"ème d fixé = ", #1, "G(Ht) = ", #2} &, {dlist, GHtlist}];
formatted = MapIndexed[Prepend[#1, First[#2]] &, formatted];
Grid[formatted]
```

Output:

```
1   ème d fixé =    1.  G(Ht) =     3.4007
2   ème d fixé =    1.01    G(Ht) =     0.360241
3   ème d fixé =    1.02    G(Ht) =     1.16721
4   ème d fixé =    1.03    G(Ht) =     5.17817
5   ème d fixé =    1.04    G(Ht) =     0.425765
6   ème d fixé =    1.05    G(Ht) =     0.331833
7   ème d fixé =    1.06    G(Ht) =     1.03875
8   ème d fixé =    1.07    G(Ht) =     1.84625
... etc.
```

Comment: you did something very useful, thank you. I'm sorry for my strange code. My goal was to display the G (Ht) value as you did. But since the p's are random, do you think it is possible to display only the p solutions of the equation?